# Как объединить эти скрипты?

Tags: javascript

```js
var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
document.querySelector('#show').onclick = function() {
  dialog.show();
};
document.querySelector('#close').onclick = function() {
  dialog.close();
};
 document.getElementById("show").onclick = function()
    {
      var myaudio = document.getElementById("myaudio");
      if(myaudio.paused == true)
      {
        document.getElementById("myaudio").play();
        this.style.backgroundColor = "Blue";
        this.style.color = "White";
      }
      else if (myaudio.paused == false)
      {
        document.getElementById("myaudio").pause();
        this.style.backgroundColor = "White";
        this.style.color = "Black";
      }
    }
```

```html
<dialog>
  <p>Это всплывающее окно, которое сделано на html5 и javascript</p>
  <button id="close">Закрыть</button>
</dialog>
<button id="show" type="button">Открыть всплывающее окно!</button>
<audio id="myaudio" src="мелодия.mp3">
</audio>
```

Помогите объединить всплывающее окно и звук при нажатии на кнопку. Без звука в хроме работает окно, но со звуком окно не разворачивается, включается музыка. В edge и firefox окно вообще не работает, но мелодия проигрывается. Как то можно их оптимизировать для этих браузеров? firefox скрывает содержимое, а edge просто вываливает... Вообще как я понял если запустить второй скрипт из первого, должно сработать? Но, как оформить и оптимизировать под все браузеры? Желательно не используя переменную, т.е. с привязкой по ид.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для использования нескольких обработчиков на одном элементе лучше воспользоваться методом [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```
document.querySelector('#show').addEventListener('click', function() {
  dialog.show();
});

document.getElementById("show").addEventListener('click', function() {...});
```

Сейчас при добавлении обработчика с музыкой - старый обработчик стирается.

Comment: Огромное человеческое спасибо)